# Error adding a test case to an angular app in stackblitz

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, stackblitz

My angular app does not work on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gm4bys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts) when I added a test case.
I'm getting this weird error: `Import error, can't find file: ./test-files.ts`.
It worked fine before adding the test.

Answer (score 1):

first you should install:

```
jasmine-core
@types/jasmine
```

then add a jasmine-setup to your project:

```
import jasmineRequire from 'jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js';
window.jasmineRequire = jasmineRequire;
```

and in `typings.d`:

```
interface Window {
  jasmineRequire: any;
  jasmineRef: any;
}

declare module 'jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js' {}
```

and in your main.ts:

```
let TEST = true;

if (TEST) {
  (function bootstrap () {
    if (window.jasmineRef) {
      location.reload();

      return;
    }

    window.onload(new Event('anything'));
    window.jasmineRef = jasmine.getEnv();
  }());
}
```

this [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-testing-gqgeny) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You added your test-files in outside of the src. Add it inside the src.

**Or** Change the main.ts import as '../test-files.ts'